# Looping through two data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to loop through two data frames at the same time

x is where i need the interest data to go in. How do i get the interest data for the variable x?

Comment: does both table have same index??

Comment: yes, they have the same. interest data is derived from margin data

Comment: can you please tell what is x in interest_data ??

Comment: x is where the interest data value needs to goes in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are same index and columns values, so is possible select second DataFrame by index and columns values from first one by [`Series.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.at.html) or [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
for r in usd_margin_data.index:
    for c in usd_margin_data.columns:
        print (usd_margin_data.at[r, c])
        print (interest_data.at[r, c])
```

Answer (score 1):

first merge both df, then apply loop.

```
df=pd.merge(usd_margin_data,interest_data,on=['acct'],suffixes=['_margin','_interest'])
```

Now you can loop each row access your both df rows from `iterrows()`.

Note: value from both df differs from it's name Suffix

Answer (score 1):

What about using `zip`:

```
for (i, row1), (j, row2) in zip(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows()):
    print(row1)
    print(row2)
```